# Instantiating a Partial Class

Tags: forms, class, partial

So I have two classes in my project, one where it says

```
namespace WindowsApplication13
{
    partial class Form1
```

and one where is says:

```
namespace WindowsApplication13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            string text1, text2, text3, text4;
            InitializeComponent();
            text1 = textBox1.Text;
            text2 = textBox2.Text;
            text3 = textBox3.Text;
            text4 = textBox4.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

}

So how do I then instansiate the latter in my Class1?

I have tried

```
Form1 : Form f1 = new Form1 : Form();
```

and

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

and

```
Form f1 = new Form();
```

But none of them works since when I try to get a variable from the Form1 : Form, I just get the error "WindowsApplication13.Form1" does not contain a definition for "text1".

Sorry if this post is messy or bad done. I can explain more in comments if needed. Thanks!

Edit: Sorry I know the syntax if Form f1 = new Form, I just forgot while writing this!

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is meant to be C#? If so, you'd declare a variable and instantiate the class like this:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
```

The `Form1 : Form` is part of the class *declaration* to show that it inherits from `Form`. You don't need it as part of the variable declaration.

(We can't tell what's wrong with regards to `text1` - you haven't told us anything about how it's declared or how you're trying to use it.)

Comment: @Jasin: Not really - that code wouldn't give the error you're describing in the code you've given. Which line is *actually* giving the error about `text1`?

Comment: string value = f1.text1; Gives me

(18,31): error CS0117: 'WindowsApplication13.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'text1'

Comment: @Jasin: Well that (18, 31) doesn't help us without knowing which file, or what the file looks like...

Comment: @Jasin: Well that's the first time you've said anything about that code... and no, it wouldn't work. You haven't declared a member of the form called `text1`. You've declared a *local* variable in the constructor, but that's not accessible outside the constructor. At this point, I really think you'd be better off going back and reading a good C# book - and ideally writing *console* apps to get to know the language better. (Starting to write GUIs before you really understand the language gives you a *big* hurdle to start with.)

Comment: Okay, yeah I see your point. But this is the last assignment before I am done with the course. I will for sure go back to the console apps once I'm done. But for now I would only like to finish this since I'm so close. 

Would you mind showing me how to declare a variable that's not local?

Comment: @Jasin: No. If you don't know how to declare a field, I suspect you haven't been paying any attention in class. If you want to *learn*, ask your teacher or read a book.

Comment: It's a distance course and I do want to learn. I do not have a teacher, and I am still waiting for my book to arrive at my home. The best I can do is search the web, and when that didn't work I made a thread on a forum. Sorry if that was wrong of me. I just thought that a this was a place where you could ask questions without being treated like an asshole. I guess I was wrong.

Edit: By the way, not being a native English speaker does not help when trying to learn, since all the information is in English. I don't think you can understand that, since you take it for granted.

Comment: @Jasin: This is a place to ask properly researched questions, carefully. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. It's *not* a place to get other people to help you pass a course that you don't actually understand.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to declare a variable is

```
Form1 varName = new Form1();
```

`Form1` is the name of your class; the fact that it's partial doesn't make any difference.

If you want to access a control in the form, you'll need to make it public first.  (or, better yet, hide it behind a public property that exposes the functionality you need)

Comment: Sorry, I know that's the correct syntax. I just forgot that when I wrote the post.

Comment: Oh great. We have the exact same answer from **SLaks** _AND_ **Skeet**